# Use of "unless" in "imaginary" conditional sentences

Tags: word-usage, conditional-constructions

Can *unless* be  used in "imaginary" conditional sentences?

Do the following sentences sound natural to you, native speakers?

> Sentence one: I couldn’t have got to the meeting on time — unless I had caught an earlier train. 
>   Sentence two: Unless he were my friend, I shouldn't expect his help.

Comment: #1 sounds a bit weird to me because I usually expect past tense *[not] X **unless** Y* to be used in contexts where ***X*** is known to be true, so ***Y*** must also be true. As in *"I wouldn't have married you unless I loved you"*. #2 sounds like an extremely dated/stilted (if not archaic) usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers re #2 maybe it's the content which makes you say that? *Unless I catch the bus, I'll be late* is a perfectly natural construction.

Comment: @Esoteric: I specifically said ***past tense [not]***. Your example is present/future[/imaginary?], and doesn't include negation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you specified past tense for #1 (X unless Y), not #2. In #2 you've made a simple blanket statement, hence my comment.

Comment: @Esoteric: I find OP's #1 a bit weird, and #2 *very* weird. Apparently you don't. But obviously I can't [weird](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffiles.nyu.edu%2Fik747%2Fpublic%2Fmedia%2Fpapers%2Fverbing-weirds-language.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffiles.nyu.edu%2Fik747%2Fpublic%2Fpapers.html&h=256&w=390&tbnid=DNEMGp7JrJczlM%3A&zoom=1&docid=KpgxlGYQiKn0tM&ei=QeOoU7OBL4m3O6qrgMgI&tbm=isch&ved=0CCMQMygCMAI&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=2496&page=1&start=0&ndsp=17) them for you, and you can't "unweird" them for me. We just see things differently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I absolutely find the language in #2 strange, though not as much you. What I mean is that I don't find the relevant structure (putting the *unless* clause at the start) weird at all. It's not clear to me *why* you find #2 weird (grammar, diction, construction...?). I've improperly assumed it was because of the structure, as the *unless* placement jumps out at me as the big difference between the two.

Comment: @Esoteric: The possibility of putting the ***unless*** clause at the front makes no difference to me - it's just normal stylistic inversion. In my first comment I gave the more familiar version of OP's construction #1, which prompts me to interpret his text as *"The fact that I got to the meeting on time **proves** that I must have caught the earlier train"* (which is semantically a bit odd, to say the least). For #2, it's specifically the word ***were*** - which unlike you I *don't* see as equivalent to ***is*** in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for clarifying. Without explanation, the earlier remarks just convey that #2 is weird, with the reader left to guess blindly at why.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use *unless* in hypotheticals. Whether or not the situation has materialized has no bearing on whether or not you can use *unless*. Indeed, the purpose of *unless* is creating conditional clauses. Consider:

1. A unless B
2. Unless B, A

The constructions are ordered differently but have the same meaning; if one structure is transformed into the other, the semantics are preserved. In both cases, the statement says that B is a necessary condition for A; A is false if B is false, and B is true if A is true. However, saying that A is true if B is true a logical error. For example, your examples:

1. A (*getting to the meeting on time*) is false if B is false, because this sentence tells us *the only way to get to the meeting on time was to catch an earlier train* (which is *if A then B*). But catching an earlier train does not guarantee arriving at the meeting on time; what if I forgot my briefcase and had to go back?
2. Here, A is *I should expect his help* and B is *he's my friend*. This sentence says *don't expect help from anyone who's not your friend* (*if not B, then not A*). Note that just because *he is your friend* does not mean *you should expect his help*.

Notice that in sentence 2, B doesn't include *not*. Using *not* or not depends on the content of the sentence. Observe:

> We will go to the park unless it rains.
>   Unless it rains, we will go to the park.

Here, B is logically *not raining*, because the statement means *if we don't go to the park, it must be raining*.

*If A then B* and *if not B then not A* do in fact have the same meaning. *For A to be true, B must also be true* allows us to deduce that *if B is false, A must also be false*. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29) for further explanation of the logic of implication.

But the discussion of predicate logic is beyond what you've asked. Simply put, it's perfectly OK to use *unless* for imaginary conditionals. As for the sample sentences, your use of *unless* is correct. They don't sound quite natural, but in both cases it's a matter of conjugation, not conditional clause structure. Here's how I'd change them:

1. I couldn't have *gotten* to the meeting on time — unless I had caught an earlier train.
2. Unless he *is* my friend, I shouldn't expect his help.

Comment: I think your final "amended version" actually changes the *meaning*. To me, OP's version asserts that the only reason I should expect his help is *because* he's my friend (a known fact). Yours implicitly admits of the possibility that in fact he *might not be* my friend.

Comment: Am I reading your comment correctly? You're you saying that changing *were* to *is* changes the meaning? The original (*were*) makes a factual statement (he is definitely my friend) and using *is* instead means *he might not be my friend*? Because I vehemently disagree if that's what you mean. Changing the tense (to match *shouldn't expect*) has no bearing on the truth of the conditional (whether or not he's my friend), and the friendship is unknown in both cases (*were* or *is*).

Comment: I think it's hard for me to vehemently defend any particular nuance to OP's [subjunctive?] ***were***, since it's probably a usage well before my time. And to my ear, ***unless*** there sounds even more "archaic/weird" than ***except***, as in [*"He would not have been held except He were man"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22He+would+not+have+been+held+except+He+were+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But we may have to *non-vehemently* disagree on this one.

Comment: Changing _was_ to _is_ in Sentence #2 was my immediate thought as well. For #1, I might've suggested change _got to_ to _made_: _I couldn't have made the meeting on time — unless I had caught an earlier train._ (Ironically, we could add a "not" in there, and it would mean the same thing: _I couldn't have made the meeting on time — not unless I had caught an earlier train._) Nevertheless, I think you've nailed it; +1.